# How to free more complex nested structs

Tags: c, struct, nested, segmentation-fault, free

Solution in comments.

```
typedef struct Vertex {
    int i;
    int color;
} vertex;

typedef struct Edge {
    vertex v1;
    vertex v2;
} edge;

typedef struct Node {
    void *p;
    struct Node *next;
} node;
```

Basically this is a linked list (of nodes).
In my program I know if a node array holds edges or vertices.

I'm not sure how to free a list of edges properly, I've tried the following:

```
static void freeEdgeList(node *list) {
    if (list == NULL) return;
    node *ptr = list;
    node *tmp;
    do {
        tmp = ptr->next;
        free(&((*((edge *)(ptr->p))).v1));
        free(&((*((edge *)(ptr->p))).v2));
        free(ptr->p);
        free(ptr);
    } while ((ptr = tmp) != NULL);
}
```

Because my struct Edge doesn't store pointers, is it enough to free the edge struct, without freeing the vertices stored in the edge?
I'm a little confused.

Edit:

```
static int addEdge(edge *e, node **list) {
    if ((*list) == NULL) {
        (*list) = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if ((*list) == NULL) return -1;
        (*list)->p = malloc(sizeof(edge));
        if ((*list)->p == NULL) return -1;
        memcpy(&((*list)->p), &e, sizeof(edge));
        (*list)->next = NULL;
    } else {
        node *tmp = (*list);
        while (tmp->next != NULL) {
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        tmp->next = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (tmp->next == NULL) return -1;
        tmp = tmp->next;
        tmp->p = malloc(sizeof(edge));
        if (tmp->p == NULL) return -1;
        tmp->next = NULL;
        memcpy(&(tmp->p), &e, sizeof(edge));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the function that adds edges to a list (initially the list passed in is NULL).
It seems to add the edges correctly because I can output the list to the console just fine.
But if I try to free with:

```
static void freeEdgeList(node *list) {
    while (list) {
        node *tmp = list;
        list = list->next;
        free(tmp->p);
        free(tmp);
    }
}
```

I get different error (segfault, invalid pointer)

Comment: `Edge` has no dynamic allocation so there should be no `free()` for v1 or v2. It is enough to just `free(ptr->p)`

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen That might be it, I actually just looked at my code and I'm using memcpy to populate v1 and v2, this means no memory was dynamically allocated right?

Comment: I don't think passing any pointer you get from `&` to `free` is ever correct in C.

Comment: Yes, `memcpy` requires memory already exists and just copies data around so there’s no allocations

Comment: In `addEdge`, your `memcpy` calls are incorrect. You are copying to/from the _address_ of a _pointer_ and _not_ what the pointer points to. You want: `memcpy((*list)->p, e, sizeof(edge))` and `memcpy(tmp->p, e, sizeof(edge))`

Comment: Also, in `addEdge`, if `*list == NULL`, you don't set it to the first element.

Comment: This code is essentially subverting `C`'s type system; is there any reason why you don't have `struct Vertex *next` inside of `Vertex` and `struct Edge *next` inside of `Edge` and getting rid of `Node`? It would be much more readable.

Answer (score 2):

You can only pass to `free` exactly what was returned from `malloc` and family.  Since you presumably called `malloc` to allocate a `node`, you only need to free a `node`.

Neither `vertex` nor `edge` contain fields that are pointers, so there is nothing else to free.  All you need to do is:

```
static void freeEdgeList(node *list) {
    while (list) {
        node *tmp = list;
        list = list->next;
        free(tmp->p);
        free(tmp);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

In the code where you add an edge, you incorrectly do this:

```
memcpy(&((*list)->p), &e, sizeof(edge));
...
memcpy(&(tmp->p), &e, sizeof(edge));
```

Since `e` is a `edge *`, what this is doing is copying the *pointer value* `e` to the field `p` instead of what it points to.  That results in the `edge` object pointed to by `p`  having invalid values.  You instead want:

```
memcpy((*list)->p, e, sizeof(edge));
...
memcpy(tmp->p, e, sizeof(edge));
```

This will copy the values contained in the `edge` that `e` points to.

Comment: Shouldn't the & also be removed from the first parameter because p is also already a pointer?

Comment: @naike Yes it should.  Edited.

Comment: @naike Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

The rule is if you don’t allocate it you don’t free it. The struct `Edge` doesn’t contain any dynamic memory allocation or pointers, as you said, so you don’t free them yourself. The memory is allocated as part of `Edge` and be freed when you free it.

So remove the `free()`s from `v1` and `v2` and only use `free(ptr->p)`.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Seems I didn't quite get it yet..

Thanks for your help, many thanks! That makes it clear to me.

```
while (list) {
    node *tmp = list;
    list = list->next;
    free(&(tmp->p));
    free(tmp);
}
```

This solution worked, I needed to pass the address of the pointer to free, not the pointer itself, I don't quite understand why though.

Comment: This is not correct.  `&(tmp->p)` is not something you allocated.   You need to call `free(tmp->p)`.  If your code crashes when you do this, then you have some other problem with your code.

Comment: @dbush I added some more info to my post, maybe you can see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's correct. Since you are not `malloc()`*ing* the `vertex` (they aren't pointers, but variables allocated inside the Edge structure) a simple `free()` for the Edge structure will suffice

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned `freeEdgeList` needs a fix [so follow their responses].

In `addEdge`, your `memcpy` calls are incorrect. You are copying to/from the *address* of a pointer and not what the pointer points to.

You want: `memcpy((*list)->p, e, sizeof(edge))` and `memcpy(tmp->p, e, sizeof(edge))`

Also, in `addEdge`, if `*list == NULL`, you don't set it to the first/new element.

Also, the code can be simplified a bit. For example, using `*list` everywhere is a bit cumbersome.

Here's a refactored version with the `memcpy` and `*list` bugs fixed:

```
static int
addEdge(edge *e, node **list)
{
    node *head = *list;
    node *cur;
    node *prev;
    int ret = -1;

    // find the end of the list
    prev = NULL;
    for (cur = head;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->next)
        prev = cur;

    do {
        // allocate new node
        cur = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (cur == NULL)
            break;
        cur->next = NULL;

        // add pointer to new edge
        cur->p = malloc(sizeof(edge));
        if (cur->p == NULL) {
            free(cur);
            break;
        }

        // copy in the edge data
        memcpy(cur->p,e,sizeof(edge);

        // link in new node
        if (prev != NULL)
            prev->next = cur;
        else
            head = cur;

        // adjust list pointer
        *list = head;

        ret = 0;
    } while (0);

    return ret;
}
```